# Print laravel errors in JSon format

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

Does anyone know how to make the application return in a general way anyexception using a response in Json format with the respective HTTP error and a descriptive message of the error occurred, without performing any type of redirection to the
time of occurrence?

This is an example of what I want

```
{
"errors": [],
"exception":
"Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\ModelNotFoundException",
"file":
"/var/www/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloqu
ent/Builder.php",
"line": 598,
"message": "No query results for model
[App\\Models\\API\\ModelName].",
"statusCode": 404
}
```

I was trying to do this from App/Exception/Handler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * The list of the inputs that are never flashed to the session on validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
            $Status = array('msg'=>$e);
            return response ($Status,$e);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Laravel APP as API? If it's API you can add `application/json` to your front-end requests. It may help you!

Answer (score 1):

If you require as per the example

There is some modification can be done to achieve it

```
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Throwable;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
public function render($request, Throwable $exception) { //..}

protected function getStatusCode(Throwable $exception): int { //..}
}
```

in Handler class add below method

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
            $statusCode = $this->getStatusCode($exception);
            $responseData = [
                'errors' => [],
                'exception' => get_class($exception),
                'file' => $exception->getFile(),
                'line' => $exception->getLine(),
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'statusCode' => $statusCode,
            ];
            return new JsonResponse($responseData, $statusCode);

    }
```

In above render method `return parent::render($request, $exception);` is default

```
protected function getStatusCode(Throwable $exception): int
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException) {
            return Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND;
        }

       if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException) {
            return Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED;
        }

        //..

        return Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create on Trait GlobalExceptionHandler in app/Traits directory

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;
use InvalidArgumentException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Throwable;

trait GlobalExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * Get error data by exception
     *
     * @param Throwable $exception
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getErrorData(Throwable $exception): array
    {
        $response = $this->getExceptionData($exception);

        if (!isset($response['error_from'])) {
            $response['error_from'] = 'application name';
        }

        if (config('app.env') == 'local' || config('app.env') == 'staging') {
            $response = array_merge(
                $response, [
                    '_message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                    '_exception' => class_basename($exception),
                    '_line' => $exception->getLine(),
                    '_file' => $exception->getFile(),
                ]
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * * Get error data by exception
     *
     * @param Throwable $exception
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getExceptionData(Throwable $exception): array
    {
        $exceptionActions = [
            'QueryException' => function (QueryException $exception) {
                $code = $exception->getCode();
                $databaseMessageByCode = [
                    23000 => __('record_already_exists'),
                ];
                return [
                    'code' => Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
                    'message' => $databaseMessageByCode[$code] ?? 'Database error!',
                ];
            },
            'ModelNotFoundException' => function (ModelNotFoundException $exception) {
                $modelName = last(explode('\\', $exception->getModel()));
                $ids = ' ' . implode(', ', $exception->getIds());
                return [
                    'code' => Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
                    'message' => "{$modelName}{$ids} " . __('does_not_exists'),
                ];
            },
            'ValidationException' => function (ValidationException $exception) {
                return [
                    'code' => Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
                    'message' =>
                        collect($exception->errors())
                            ->flatten()
                            ->first() ?? $exception->getMessage(),
                    'errorMessages' => $exception->errors(),
                ];
            },
            'NotFoundHttpException' => function (NotFoundHttpException $exception) {
                return [
                    'code' => $exception->getStatusCode(),
                    'message' => __('http_request_does_not_exist'),
                ];
            },
            'Exception' => function (Throwable $exception) {
                $exceptionCode = Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
                $exceptionMessage = __('Internal Server Error');
                if ($exception->getCode() > 200) {
                    $exceptionCode = $exception->getCode();
                    $exceptionMessage = $exception->getMessage();
                }
                return [
                    'code' => $exceptionCode,
                    'message' => $exceptionMessage,
                ];
            },
        ];
        $className = isset($exceptionActions[class_basename($exception)])
            ? class_basename($exception)
            : 'Exception';

        return $exceptionActions[$className]($exception);
    }
}
```

And in App/Exception/Handler.php use Trait to render the exception

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use App\Traits\GlobalExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    use GlobalExceptionHandler;

    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array<int, class-string<Throwable>>
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->renderable(function (Throwable $e) {
            $errorData = $this->getErrorData($e);
            return response()->json($errorData, $errorData['code']);
        });

        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        
        });
    }
}
```